# Efficient method of calculating a matrix of pairwise distances?

Tags: python, matrix

I have a list of objects `list_of_objects` which I cluster together using `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage()`. As input `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage()` takes a condensed distance matrix. I calculate the condensed distance matrix by using `itertools.combinations` to only compare unique combinations:

```
distances = map(do_comparison, itertools.combinations(list_of_objects, 2))
```

Even so, the time it takes grows fast with the size of `list_of_objects`. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: By "grows fast", it should grow as O(N^2) as (up to a constant factor) there are N^2 pairs one can make.

Comment: If you can live with some error in the distance (and even if you think you can't, you probably can), you could use a tree code (O(N log N)) or vector multipole expansion (O(N) if you do it right, but it's tricky to get that behaviour in practice at smallish N).

Answer (score 3):

If there is a critical cutoff where the distance do not matter anymore (a data-dependent answer) you can try using the spare matrix representation from [`scipy.spatial.KDTree.sparse_distance_matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.sparse_distance_matrix.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree.sparse_distance_matrix). The knowledge of the KDTree should significantly cut down on the time computing the longer range distances.

To make it work with the clustering you may want to note:

> Computes a distance matrix between two KDTrees, **leaving as zero any distance greater than max_distance**.

and change the zero to `np.inf`.

Answer (score 1):

Distance calcs are symmetric: d(x, y) = d(y, x), so no need to duplicate them.  And all the diagonal terms are zero: d(x, x) = 0.

But once you know that, there's no getting around the number of calculations that need to be done.

Fortunately, they are easily parallelizable.    Create the matrix with multiple threads and you'll speed things up.

Comment: `itertools.combinations` makes sure that they are not duplicated and that it doesn't calculate the diagonal. I already got them paralalized, but with large amounts of objects to compare this is not enough.